# MySQL Workbench Inserts

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL Workbench 5.2.28 for designing my database schema. I need to insert default data into some tables which can be done using the "Inserts" tab. However, it seems like it only allows entering data manually, one row at a time. I have an OUTFILE with several hundred rows that I would like to insert.

Is this possible with MySQL Workbench? Would creating separate MySQL scripts for importing default data be a better approach?

Comment: I would use something like EMS' Data Import for MySQL for something like this, it isn't free but there is a 30 days demo if I remember correctly http://www.sqlmanager.net/products/mysql/dataimport

Comment: Prefer using it as a separate script, sometimes MySql drops the insert values. A real pain if you have 100 lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am now using separate sql scripts for inserting my data as there doesn't seem to be an easy way to add bulk inserts to MySQL workbench.

Comment: You means that we cannot use MySQL Workbench to "pre-insert" default data (for debug) in the `insert` tab before `Forword Engineering...`?

Answer (score 4):

Generate CSV (quoted if you have comas in values) in Excel for example, then just copy/paste all rows into workbench via 'inserts' tab for each table in model. 
Works with Workbench version 5.2.40.

Comment: Workbench 6.0 has a small import-button for CSV in the Inserts tab. Make sure you separate with comma instead of semicolon.

Answer (score 3):

In the MySQL Workbench Version 6.2 you will find a Import Button which alows you to Import Inserts from a CSV File with "," as delemiter.

Comment: In the latest version, you can indeed insert large files, with any delimiter, in CSV-style or JSON format.

Comment: Looks like this will generate separate insert statements for each row. When I have only few values per row to insert, I usually a create a SQL script that looks like this `INSERT INTO tmp_data (cust_id) values (1001),(1002),(1003),(1004);` Inserting 100k records this way takes just couple seconds. The script can be "generated" for example in Excel, just add few extra columns where you put the required parenthesis and then copy-paste that to text editor.

Answer (score 0):

You are right there is no way I know doing this automatically. The only thing you can do is to generate all your inserts scripts in a single time by doing a forward engeniering and then by copying the insert statements at the end of the generated script (You must check the option "Generate INSERT statements").