# MySQL WorkBench with inserts from external source

Tags: mysql, insert, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL workbench 5.2.38 (latest) to design my database. I am using NaviCat to manage the database server.

I have designed the database, but would like to be able to insert some default data. MySQL WorkBench comes with an "Inserts" table to insert the table data. However, it is very tedious as each entry must be typed in manually. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279058/mysql-workbench-inserts), but the solution the asker came up with was to just use a seperate script.

In my case, I would like to import the data from the live database or perhaps some other external file.

I have tried using `Database->Synchronize Model` and attempted to synchronize data from the database back to the model, but for some reason, workbench just crashes, or says it is completed successfully, but the data never shows up in my model.

Has anyone successfully got inserts from an external source imported into a workbench model? If you have built large database driven applications which ships with a lot of default data (inserts), I would love to hear how you dealt with the default inserts in a managable way as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to deal with the mass inserts in an easy way, so I ended up just writing a PHP script and using ORM.

At least this way, it is much easier to make changes to the default data.

If someone can some up with a better solution, I will mark that as correct.

Comment: Can I have that PHP script? Or what is ORM and how ORM can do it? I have the same problem. I want to insert values on a local DB, then synchronize it with my model and then Forward Engineer it to a remote DB.

Comment: @AndreasLympouras It's nothing special. I just use MySQL workbench to forward engineer the schema into the database. Then I run an install script written in PHP to insert the values. I am using http://redbeanphp.com/ as my ORM, but any ORM or even PDO can do the job.

Comment: What is an ORM? What does it does? I just want to store my local rows (inserts) of each table to my remote database.

Comment: ORM is object relational mapping. It just allows us to talk to the database in an object oriented way. It makes writing code easier, rather than having to write raw SQL using PDO. In anycase, if you do not use ORMs, just use PDO and insert the data using SQL. Then, to initialize your app, use MySQL workbench to forward engineer to the remote server and then run your PHP script to insert the data.

Answer (score 1):

Generate CSV (quoted if you have comas in values) in Excel for example, than just copy/paste all rows into workbench via 'inserts' tab for each table in model. Works with Workbench version 5.2.40.